# Force a specific test-variant as preview in google optimize

Tags: preview, ab-testing, google-optimize

is it possible forcing to see a specific test-variant in the browser/preview?

I have AB Test and it's already running. Now I want to see only variant A or variant B - how can I force the specific variant? Maybe with some URL parameters.

Comment: Preview modes are still available in Optimize, just like during the test design phase. Is there a specific use case, where it not sufficient?

Comment: Unfortunately, Preview mode is not enough. I need to show some external people, who don't have access to Google Optimize, a specific variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the last digit in the `_gaexp` cookie, using the browser dev tools, to force a specific variant.

https://support.google.com/optimize/thread/16756967?hl=en&msgid=16794463

Comment: Thanks Codekie! This is exactly what I was searching for.
Figured out - sometimes the cookie name is `gtm_experiment`